# wp_update_post call really slow when official Facebook plugin is installed

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, facebook

I'm having this weird issue, if i install my plugin and the official Facebook plugin the call to wp_update_post() becomes really slow. I've done some benchmark and it goes up to almost two seconds. If i disable Facebook plugins it reverts back to normal. Anyone knows what should i do to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

This is beacuse facebook plugins does some really intensive checks on every save_post and this slows down calls to wp_update_post and wp_save_post to a crawl ( about 2 seconds for each call ). If you want you  can remove them

```
remove_action( 'save_post', 'fb_add_page_mention_box_save' );
remove_action( 'save_post', 'fb_add_friend_mention_box_save' );
```

The crazy thing is that facebook does a login for in both of these calls: 0.6 second each, they never cache anything!